# When to use enum, class or tags?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, enums, tags

Imagine you have a page that is of a specific page type (for example normal page, account page etc). The page is represented by a Page object.

My question is, how would you assign a page type to a page?

I see these options:

1. by using a PageType enum that is set in the Page object.
2. by using a PageType class, and assigning instances of it in the Page object.
3. by using page tags, which are simple strings associated with the Page object.

Option 1 is code-only approach, so adding new page types means changing (core) code.
Option 2 is more flexible, but there is additional overhead in having to maintain these page types. 
Option 3 is very flexible, because there's no maintenance and it's extendable to other mechanisms than page type. But you can easily break things because there are no constraints.

What would be other objective reasons to choose one over the other?

Comment: Do you want the user of your application to be able to add new page types, or is there a fixed number of types? Does every page have exactly one type, or do you expect pages sharing two or more types?

Comment: The user cannot add page types, he can choose between existing page types if he creates a page. The web developer however, can define new page types; and use it in certain widgets to make decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lack of details regarding a system design and pages requirements, number of different page types to support and difference between pages itself, so hard to make such decision. In such case I would recommend to [keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and use [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

- If pages has own specific business logic you can stick with class per Page type, but do it carefully only when really page-specific logic there.
- Think about UserControl/CustomControl feature (assuming you are usign `ASP.NET`) so you can split page by a set of controls which is responsible on the part of Page functionality, so in this way you'll keep [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and build less coupled system.
- Some logic should be `extracted` from Page entities itself into external helpers/factories/repositories and then injected in Page class.

Regarding objectives,
you should define how many pages could be in place potentially and which level of flexibility should be provided. Also keep in mind such things like extensibility and maintenance of a system.

Answer (score 2):

What about option 4?

Creating an (abstract) base class with basic page behavior, and a subclass for each specific page. This is the best design if you expect differences in a lot of different places. It prevents having to write `switch` statements evaluating the enum in dozens of places.

Prevent using 'magic' strings, so definitely prefer using approach 1 or 2 over 3. Based on your requirements using [the strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to plugin in different behaviors can be a viable option as well. This gives even more flexibility, but initializing your class will become a bit more cumbersome. Of course, this behavior again can be wrapped in a class/factory method doing this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.

The obvious question is why you only want to identify the type of page? The identification itself is not useful. You most likely want to do something more with the page.

I would create interfaces for all kinds of pages, like `IAccountingPage` and then have some kind of repository. If you need to pre process a page before it's displayed create a filter interface like `IPagePreFilter<T> where T : IPage` and then implement it like:

```
public class DiscountFilter : IPagePreFilter<ISalesPage>
{
    public void Process(ISalesPage page)
    {
        if (page.Product.Id == 1234)
            page.AddParagraph("Product is at amazing 50% off");
    }
}
```

Summary: Don't try to identify pages to have logic like `if (page.PageType == PageEnum.Accounting) bla bla` because it breaks Liskovs Substitution Principle. Do a more robust solution like the one I suggested.