# C enum tags: When/Why to Use

Tags: c, enums

I'm trying to understand the full syntax of a C enum.  For decades, I've successfully used simple enums like the below:

```
enum {
  IDLE,
  BUSY,
  FAILED
};
```

But I see the formal definition of a C enum also allows a tag and instance name like the below:

```
enum STATE {
  IDLE,
  BUSY,
  FAILED
} appstate;
```

When and why would I ever use **"STATE"** or **"appstate"**? For the life of me I can't think of a reason.

Questions [8414188](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414188) and [7386805](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386805) beat around the bush on this issue but were not enlightening.

**UPDATE 5/4/19**
I offer some clarifications to my question in response to answers per below:
1. I *do* use prefixes, e.g. STATE_IDLE, but theses were trimmed in my bare-bones examples above.
2. I *have* examined several code examples using enums. These confirmed my understanding of the enhanced syntax but did nothing to explain *why*.
3. I routinely place my anonymous enum in a project-wide .h file, and this seems to work just fine. I still can't figure out *why* I would want to waste keystrokes to use the politically-correct, enhanced syntax. **Is it just for (allegedly) improved readability?** Or am I missing something?

Comment: The supposed advantage of using a tag and then using variables of that type is that debuggers will generally be able give you a nice symbolic representation for the values of a variable of that type.

Comment: It is not unlikely that you'll want to declare a variable or a function parameter of the enum type.  Also helps a decent compiler generate a diagnostic when you use the wrong enum identifier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would like to code (and that is actually very common, e.g. `enum audit_state` in the [Linux kernel's `kernel/audit.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/audit.h?id=refs/tags/v4.10.13#L36))

```
enum STATE {
  IDLE,
  BUSY,
  FAILED
};
```

<sup>Such an `enum` definition is likely to go (by convention) into some public header file. You might adopt the convention to share a common prefix for the various enum values, so write `STA_IDLE` or `STA_BUSY` instead of `IDLE` and `BUSY`; sometimes I take the convention of suffixing the `enum` tag, here `STATE`, with `_en` so I would rather code `enum STATE_en { STA_IDLE, STA_BUSY,` ... `};`</sup>

if you want to use (notably for readability purposes) `enum STATE` as the type of e.g. some variable or formal:

```
enum STATE global_state; // a global variable
void print_state(enum STATE); // a formal
```

or in a typedef:

```
typedef enum STATE stateT;
```

etc....

Your `appstate` is just a variable of type `enum STATE` (like my `global_state` is).

I do recommend *studying the source code* of some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) in C (it does not has to be as complex as the Linux kernel; you can find many examples on [github](http://github.com/)).

Don't forget to enable all warnings when compiling (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), because the compiler might warn you (with explicit `enum`s) in many useful cases (e.g. a `switch` on that `enum` missing some `case`....).

BTW, C programming practically wants a lot of *conventions* and you might explicit them (e.g. in some coding style guide).

Answer (score 2):

**About STATE**

Usually, when you are creating an enum, you want to use it as a type.

When you don't use any name, it's just a way for declaring integer constants.

Moreover, using anonymous enumerations, you don't need to specify the enum name to refer to its members, but it could lead to name clashes.

**About appstate**

It is a variable of type `enum STATE`.